# Word meaning since its existence

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the sentence:

> The figure grew steadily since its six-month ___________.

So I'm looking for a word to complete the thought, given that this statistic/figure has been in existence for six months. I had thought of "inception" or "half-life" but these choices seemed to be kind of stretching it.

### Question

What is an appropriate word choice for my example sentence? Need to sound formal/professional, but not necessarily high-syllable.

Comment: What exactly is *figure* in this context? The specific type of noun will determine the appropriateness of the word used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Existence** is a period of time. In your example six-months.

**Inception** is the beginning of existence.

“Since” references a point in time, such as the inception.

Therefore, your sentence should be modified to either change “since” to “during” or “in”, or to remove or move “six month”.

*The figure grew steadily* during *its six-month existence.*

*The figure grew steadily since its inception. [six-months ago.]*

Answer (score 1):

The structure seems awkward. Maybe try switching it around?

From a promising start, the figure grew steadily for the first six months.